# grep after find don't show file content

Tags: grep, find

Usually with `grep -r "word" <path>` you see:

```
<file_path>: <line_with_word>
```

but if you did something like:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" -exec grep "word" {} \;
```

You can see only the content, with grep -l you can only see the file, and I want both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re using GNU `grep`, the `-H` option will ensure that the output is prefixed with the filename in all cases:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" -exec grep -H "word" {} \;
```

Incidentally, you could use `+` here instead of `\;` to run `grep` on as many files as possible at a time:

```
find . -type f -name "*.py" -exec grep -H "word" {} +
```